# Multiply two data frames

Tags: r, dataframe

How can I multiply two data frames with each other, they have the same size and identical column names: aaa, bbb, ccc, 0, 1, 2, 3, ..., n
I want to multiply the columns 0, 1, 2, 3, ..., n, additionally multiplying each by the value in the ccc column and get a new data frame.
My sample data frame:

```
| aaa | bbb | ccc | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | ... | n |
| --- | --- | --- | - | - | - | - | --- | - |
| EU  | AU  |2    |0,2|0,5|0,7|1  | ... |5  |
| EU  | PL  |3    |0,4|0,9|0,1|2  | ... |3  |
| ..  | ..  |..   |.. |.. |.. |.. | ... |.. |
| GR  | IN  |5    |0,4|0,9|0,1|2  | ... |3  |
| WR  | ES  |4    |0,6|0,3|0,2|4  | ... |1  |
```

I want to perform the following action:

```
| aaa | bbb | ccc | 0                 | 1                 |2                  |3              | ... | n    |
| --- | --- | --- | ---               | ---               | ---               | ----          | --- | ---  |
| EU  | AU  |2    |multi (ccc;0,2;0,2)|multi (ccc;0,5;0,5)|multi (ccc;0,7;0,7)|multi(ccc;1;1) | ... |multi(ccc;5;5) |
```

Comment: df$0 is not going to succeed. If you really do have a column named 0 the you will need to surround it with backticks. If you read such a file with header =TRUE, the the column name will be named something like V.0 or X.0

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow. Could you please include your data as an object in the question: use dput(your_data)  This allows the data to be easily copied to help with verifying a solution minimal reproducible example is a good place to look for guidance. Assume the two data frames are not identical, Also could you clarify which columns expressly need multiplying for example new column 0 = `df1$ccc` * `df1$0` * `df1$2`, * `df2$0` * `df2$2` could be an interpretation of the expected output... it this correct? (Assume numeric column names back ticked)

Comment: I am looking for a solution exactly:
0 = df1 $ ccc * df1 $ 0 * df1 $ 2
ccc is identical for the lines in df1 and df2.
What's more, columns named 0, 1, 2, 3 can be called x0, x1, x2, x3 ..., xn
Their names don't have to be numbers but text. The aaa, bbb and ccc columns are identical in df1 and df2.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

```
My data frame:
aaa <- c("EU", "EU", "IN", "GR")
bbb <- c("AU", "PL", "IN", "ES")
ccc <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
h0 <- c(2, 2, 3, 4)
h1 <- c(3, 4, 3, 1)
h2 <- c(3, 5, 5, 5)
#..
#hn

df1 <- data.frame(aaa, bbb, ccc, h0, h1, h2)
df2 <- data.frame(aaa, bbb, ccc, h0, h1, h2)
print (df1)
print (df2)

aaa <- c("EU", "EU", "IN", "GR")
bbb <- c("AU", "PL", "IN", "ES")
ccc <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
h0 <- c(1*2*2, 2*2*2, 3*3*3, 4*4*4)
h1 <- c(1*3*3, 2*4*4, 3*3*3, 4*1*1)
h2 <- c(1*3*3, 2*5*5, 3*5*5, 4*5*5)
#..
#hn

df3 <- data.frame(aaa, bbb, ccc, h0, h1, h2)
print (df3)
```